# Ideias para fazer um histórico privado

Tags: java

```
try {
    Connection lig = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost/gym", "root", "0000");
    PreparedStatement inst = lig
            .prepareStatement("SELECT ph.Produtos_idProdutos, ph.Historico_idHistorico, p.Nome, p.Price "
                    + "FROM produtos_has_historico ph "
                    + "JOIN produtos p "
                    + "ON p.idProdutos=ph.Produtos_idProdutos");
    ResultSet rs = inst.executeQuery();
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tableHistorico
            .getModel();
    model.setNumRows(0);
    while (rs.next()) {
        Object novaLinha[] = { rs.getInt("ph.Historico_idHistorico"),
                rs.getInt("ph.Produtos_idProdutos"),
                rs.getString("p.Nome"), rs.getDouble("p.Price") };
        model.addRow(novaLinha);

    }
} catch (SQLException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

CardLayout card = (CardLayout) frame.getContentPane().getLayout();
card.show(frame.getContentPane(), "Histórico");
```

Este é o código que eu utilizo para adicionar à minha tabela, os produtos. Mas também consigo ver produtos de outros utilizadores, não sei se tenho de mudar alguma coisa na base de dados. Obrigado pela a ajuda.

Comment: Qual exatamente é a sua pergunta? O comando SQL está trazendo mais coisas do que deveria, é isso?

Comment: Na sua tabela você tem alguma coluna que indique quem é o usuário que possui aquele histórico ? Algo como ph.usuario_id ? Se tiver, basta adicionar a cláusula WHERE na sua query... WHERE ph.usuario_id = " + codigo_usuario_atual